# Code snippet to create offline cube with KPIs?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

How to create an offline cube with KPIs?
By using the below snippet, we can create the offline cube with Measures and Dimensions but we need the KPIs as well. So kindly let me know the code snippet which creates the offline cube with KPIs information along with Measure and Dimension.

CODE SNIPPET:

```
CREATE GLOBAL CUBE [LocalReseller]
   Storage 'C:\LocalAWReseller1.cub'
   FROM [Adventure Works]
   (
      MEASURE  [Adventure Works].[Reseller Sales Amount],
      DIMENSION [Adventure Works].[Reseller],
      DIMENSION [Adventure Works].[Date]
   )
```

Thanks in advance.